# Javascript (Jquery) Loop not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

this is my first post on the forum. Here i have a javascript attempting to loop, and to set each element as an active class, then wait, remove the class and add it to the next element.
My problem is that it does the first one, then no more...

```
var i = 1;

function myLoop() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        var i = 1;
        var j = (i - 1);

        $("#nH" + j).removeClass("active");
        $("#nH" + i).addClass("active");

        i++;
        if (i < 5) {
            myLoop();
        }
    }, 3000)
}

myLoop();​
```

Comment: It looks like it will call `myLoop` indefinitely... and it's not really a loop, it's recursion. The whole approach is a bit confusing.

Comment: Your code executes fine in Chrome. What browser are you using? Are you getting any error? Maybe it's detecting the infinite recursion.

Comment: What does the javascript console say? anything? which browser?

Comment: What do you want it to do after 5 iterations - stop or start all over again?

Comment: This aproach is really confusing and got some errors. Like i++ before if(i < 5). And it is infinite... i will never be 5. It will call myLoop() over and over again. Browsers will stop this script from running,seeing the infinte loop. Edith: you just set var i = 1 on two spots. One spot is global, the other spot is a private variable of myLoop(). Delete var i = 1 in myLoop() and set i++ after your if statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove `var i = 1;` before `var j = (i - 1);` and add it here

```
  if (i < 5) {
     i=1;
     myLoop(); 

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is because you are assigning i equal to 1 and therefor it is removing the class of the same element again and again. So it is actually being called multiple times but you don't realize as the effect is the same. Problem is with your logic with the variable i and j. Try this.

```
var i = 1;

function myLoop() {
    setTimeout(function() {

        var j = (i - 1);

        $("#nH" + j).removeClass("active");
        $("#nH" + i).addClass("active");

        i++;
        if (i==5)
           i=1;
        if (i < 5) {
            myLoop();
        }
    }, 3000)
}

myLoop();​
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution without using loop and global variable. The [example](http://jsfiddle.net/TADBm/1/).

```
setInterval((function(min, max){
    var i = min;
    return function() {
        $("#nH"+i).addClass("active");
        $("#nH"+(i===min ? max : i-1)).removeClass("active");
        if (++i > max ) i = min;
    }
})(0, 4), 1000);
```

Answer (score -1):

because you need to call setTimeout again in your loop

```
var i = 1;                    

function myLoop () {       

    var j = (i-1);

$("#nH" + j).removeClass("active");
$("#nH" + i).addClass("active");

    i++;
  if (i < 5) {        
     return setTimeout(myLoop,3000); /// <- HERE       
  }                   
}

setTimeout(myLoop,3000);
```

Comment: This is not right. This way he'll get two timeouts before the subsequent events happen.